# Login System Error - PDO

Tags: php, html, authentication, pdo

I'm having an issue with my login system using PDO. When you login with the correct password, it will just refresh the page even though the form is linked to another page & when you login you'll be redirected to "home.php" not "index.php"

```
<?php
include('./includes/connect.php');

$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$email = sanitize($_POST['email']);
$password = nCrypt(sanitize($_POST['password']));

if(isset($submit)) {
    if(isset($email) && isset($password)) {
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->execute();

        $r = $query->fetch();
        $pass2 = $r['password'];
        $first = $r['first'];
        $last = $r['lastname'];
        $username = $r['username'];

        if(strcasecmp($password, $pass2) == 0) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $r['user'];
            $_SESSION['first'] = $r['first'];
            $_SESSION['last'] = $r['last'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $r['id'];
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php?e=incorrect');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: index.php?e=empty');
    }
}
?>
```

Basically, when you enter the correct password nothing happens. My form is:

```
<!-- index.php -->
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <legend>Email Address</legend>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required><br>
    <legend>Password</legend>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

As you can see it links to another page, yet when when you enter in the correct password, it'll just refresh the page the form is on, when it suppose to redirect you to "home.php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to select with this statement

```
SELECT password FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

Then where are you going to get

```
$first = $r['first'];
$last = $r['lastname'];
$username = $r['username'];
```

from?

Do a

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

OR

```
SELECT password, first,last,username FROM users WHERE email = ?
```

Also why complicate life do a simple if to test for the right password:

```
if($password == $pass2) {
```

Also it would be worth checking that the password on the database was actually encrypted in the same way you are encrypting the user input.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. I feel very stupid lmao. I just took a second look at the query.

Comment: No sweat, we all do it. To close to the problem to see the obvious.